# Angular: Does <router-outlet> has to be on the same page on which routerLink is there?

Tags: angular

On my website implemented in angular 4.0, I want to have 3 pages, say `Page1`, `Page2`, and `Page3` and there are 3 `routerLink`s on the main page (home page):

```
<a routerLink="page1" routerLinkActive="active">Page1</a>
<a routerLink="page2" routerLinkActive="active">Page2</a>
<a routerLink="page3" routerLinkActive="active">Page3</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But what I want is if there is a `routerLink` for `Page2` on `Page1` as well, how can I load **only** `Page2` on clicking that link?

**`Page1` html snippet:**

```
<a routerLink="page2" routerLinkActive="active">Page2</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Clicking on the above `Page2` link located on `Page1` appends the `Page2` content to the `Page1` content. But I want only `Page2` content.

**Routes config:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component }
];
```

Comment: can you show us the routes configuration?

Comment: @DanielSeguraPérez Added routes config as well

Comment: In your case, you should only need the top level router outlet. Also try changing your routerlink to `[routerLink]="['page2']"`